# Mail settings from php.ini using ini_set()

Tags: php, email

I'm having a problem regarding with the custom `ini_set()` for Mail settings. The problem is that somehow my PHP server does not detect the custom `ini_set()` just like below.

```
ini_set('SMTP','mail_Server.com'); // the custom server that I want to use
ini_set('smtp_port','465'); // custom port according to the server mail
ini_set('sendmail_from','send@mail.com'); // email use to send the mail

$recipients = array(
    "email@1.com",
    "email@2.com");
$f_to = implode(',', $recipients); // recipients email address

$subject = "subjects";
$body = 'body content';
$body.= 'message content';
$headers = "From send@mail.com";


mail($f_to, $subject, $body, $header); // email sent
```

The code work just fine and the script did sent me an email, but not from the custom server that I want it to. Instead it sent the email according to default settings from `php.ini`.

I appreciate any help or comment regarding to this matter. Thanks!

Comment: Does the server run Windows? The SMTP settings work only on Windows. If you're on Linux, use a library like http://swiftmailer.org

Comment: phpmailer is another great library http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: I see. The server run on Linux. Thanks for the info!